# Marklogic server won't start anymore

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

To end a pipeline process that was taking way too long I thought it would be a good idea to "disable" the cpf:restart trigger and then restart the server.

Unfortunately, if the shutdown was successful, the server will not come back up again.

In the log, I can tell where the problem is coming from:

> 2016-10-23 07:31:38.448 Emergency: Initialization: XDMP-UNBPRFX: (err:XPST0081) Prefix pagedtext has no namespace binding

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to fix this if the server is not up and running. Is there any files I should be looking into for mention of this prefix? Any way to "force" Marklogic to ignore the issue, at least while it is starting, so I can investigate and fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found references to this prefix in several files in the folder "**MarkLogic\Data**".

In particular in the files "**groups.xml**" and "**databases.xml**".

I ended up commenting out the prefix definitions and Marklogic was able to start again.

Obviously other things remain broken which I will describe in a separate post ;-)